# How to get html data from "this" object - Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to redo a function that was working with jQuery using only vanilla js. I can't seem to figure out how to get the data I need from the this object. I need to get the value of the parentid data attribute but nothing I've tried has worked!

Within my function if I include

`console.log(this);`

I get the output:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="1" data-groupingtype="2">Text Content</a>
```

So I know that the data I need is within the object. I'm aware of the getAttribute("AttributeName") function but I don't have access to it through the *this* object.

Here is how the function is set up.

```
const selectionList = document.querySelectorAll("#selectionList li a");
for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; i++) {
    selectionList[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector("#selectionButton span:first-child").textContent = (this.textContent);
        console.log(this);
        selectedParentID = parseInt($(this).data("parentid")); //this is what I can't figure out how to replace
        selectedType = $(this).data("type"); //and this
    });
}
```

This is the jQuery function I'm trying to replace:

```
$("#selectionList li a").on("click", function () {
    $("#selectionButton span:first-child").text($(this).text());
    selectedParentID = parseInt($(this).data("parentid"));
    selectedType = $(this).data("groupingtype");
    if (selectedParentID && selectedType && selectedOtherType) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="selectionContainer" class="form-group">
                    <button id="selectionButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Select Grouping</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul id="selectionList" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="11" data-type="1">Option 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="11" data-type="2">Option 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="11" data-type="3">Option 3</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="12" data-type="1">Alternate 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="12" data-type="2">Alternate 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="12" data-type="3">Alternate 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Comment: please share the complete html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an item, which has `data-foo="bar"` then you can get this attribute via

```
foo.getAttribute("data-foo")
```

The `data()` function is a jQuery `function` and will not work with Vanilla JS. Subsequently you will need to use

```
this.getAttribute("data-parentid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few changes you can do

Instead of doing

`document.querySelector("#selectionButton span:first-child").textContent` 
you can do

`let getButtonSpan = document.getElementById('selectionButton').firstElementChild;`

this will giive the first child inside this dom element with id `selectionButton`

You can use `forEach` though conventional `for` loop is equally good. Use the argument of `forEach` to get the anchor tag dom & add event listener to it. On click of it get the text by using `innerHTML` & set it to the first child of button.

Beside getAttribute you can also use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to retrive the `data` property from a dom.

In your code which is replacement of jquery you are using `$(this).data("parentid")` which is violating your objective

```js
let getButtonSpan = document.getElementById('selectionButton').firstElementChild;
document.getElementById('selectionList').querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    getButtonSpan.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
    let selectedParentID = item.dataset.parentid;
    let selectedType = item.dataset.type;
    if (selectedParentID && selectedType) {
      doSomeThing(selectedParentID, selectedType);
    }
  })

})

function doSomeThing(a, b) {
  console.log(`selectedParentID : ${a} & selectedType :${b}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectionContainer" class="form-group">
  <button id="selectionButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span>Select Grouping</span>&nbsp;
       <span class="caret"></span>
  
  </button>
  <ul id="selectionList" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="11" data-type="1">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="11" data-type="2">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="11" data-type="3">Option 3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="12" data-type="1">Alternate 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="12" data-type="2">Alternate 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" data-parentid="12" data-type="3">Alternate 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```